# What does it mean for a distribution to have support on the real axis?

Tags: fourier-analysis, laplace-transform, distribution-theory

What does it mean for a distribution to have support on the
real axis?  I'm ask this because I just saw the following:

If $d$ is a distribution with support on the real axis, the Laplace-Borel transform coincides with the Fourier transform.

My attempt: Let $\mathcal{L}(d)(\xi)\equiv \langle d(z),\mathrm{e}^{z\xi}\rangle$ the Laplace-Borel of the distribution $d$. Here, $z$ and $\xi$ are in $\mathbb{C}$ and $d(z)$ indicates the variable where the distributions acts.

\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}(d)(-i\xi)&\equiv\langle d(z),\mathrm{e}^{-iz\xi}\rangle\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d(x)\mathrm{e}^{-ix \xi} dx\text{ ? }\\
&=\mathcal{F}(d(x))(\xi)\text{ ?}
\end{align}
where $d(x)=d(z=x+i0)$?

Comment: I suppose that this is about distributions on $\mathbb C.$ Then I interpret "support on the real axis" as the distribution vanishing outside of the real axis. For example, $u(x+iy)=\delta(y)$ has support on the real axis.